# pd.to_timedelta('1D') works while pd.to_timedelta('D') fails. Issue when converting ferquency to timedelta

Tags: pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I'm encountering a silly problem I guess.

Currently, I'm using `pd.infer_freq` to get the frequency of a dataframe index. Afterwards, I use `pd.to_timedelta()` to convert this frequency to a timedelta object, to be added to another date.

This works quite fine, except when the dataframe index has a frequency which can be expressed as a single time unit (eg. 1 day, or 1 minute).

To be more precise,

```py
freq = pd.infer_freq(df)
# let's say it gives '2D' because data index is spaced on that interval
timedelta = pd.to_timedelta(freq)
```

works, while

```py
freq = pd.infer_freq(df)
# let's say it gives 'D' because data index is spaced on that interval
timedelta = pd.to_timedelta(freq)
```

fails and returns

```
ValueError: unit abbreviation w/o a number
```

This could work if I supplied '1D' instead of 'D' though.
I could try to check if the first character of the `freq` string is numeric, and add '1' otherwise, but that seems quite cumbersome.

Is anyone aware of a better approach ?

Comment: `timedelta = pd.to_timedelta(freq if freq[0].isdecimal() else '1' + freq)` is not **that** bad :P

Comment: Well, maybe. I guess I wonder whether this is not a sign I'm doing something wrong though. It seems weird pandas components do not behave much better together (note I don't want to blame the lib's authors neither)

Comment: No, yeah I see your point and I agree. I just have seen worse! I don't think you are doing anything wrong though.